# How to get Http path of recorded video in flash using Flash media server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http, rtmp, flash-media-server

I am using influxis flash media server for recording of video using my flash application. Recording part is working fine and i can also find recorded video on fms server as well in .flv format.

Now i have to convert that video on server to mp4 format and also i have to play recorded video to mobile. For this i need a http path of recorded video so that i can access that video and can also play on my device but I have only RTMP url of video which cannot be played by IOS or Android application.

Please provide some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You know you can record directly to mp4 on FlashPlayer 10.2+  .  No reason to use .flv's anymore

Comment: Adobe media server can dish out http video to mobile. https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/configure-dynamic-streaming-live-streaming.html

Comment: Pipe will do all of that for you (record & covert to mp4 with proper codecs, push top your sftp/s3/dropbox, send you webhook with playback links, etc.) https://addpipe.com